# Preventing the virtual and override in inheritance chain

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism

Please note: This is a conceptual question and not related to production specific code.

Suppose we have Class A with virtual method GetBonus(int value)

Next, we derive a class from this called Class B. In this Class B we override the method GetBonus.

Next, we derive a class from Class B called Class C.

Now class C can also override the GetBonus method of class A.

Question:

1. Whether Class C overrides the method definition of Class A or of the Class B?
2. In Class C, How can the overriding of the method of Class A be prevented ?
3. In Class C, How can the overriding of the method of Class B be prevented ?

I know that there is a SEALED keyword for sealing the virtual overridden methods. But above questions will help me clear my doubts.

Comment: This is a genuine query.. Esspecially point 2 and 3 are hey possible at all?

Comment: Instead of telling about your code, show the classes you have in mind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Questions 2 and 3 boil down to the same thing basically, and `sealed` is indeed the answer here.

Perhaps you asked it a bit vague, but you can only prevent overriding of virtual methods in derived classes. Not in the derived class itself. In the end, for both questions 2 and 3, you have only one option:

```
class A
{
    public virtual void GetBonus(int value) { }
}

class B : A
{
    public sealed override void GetBonus(int value) { } // We seal this method
}

class C : B
{
    public override void GetBonus(int value) // This line is invalid
      // because it cannot override the sealed member from class B.        
    {   }
}
```

This will prevent method `GetBonus` from getting overridden in derived classes.

This sample also answers question 1. It gives a compilation error because class C's override of `GetBonus` is attempting to override the version provided by class `B` and not the one provided by `A`. This is true because overriding the one from `A` would obviously work as it isn't `sealed`.

Comment: 1 question: SInce B derives from A, and C derives from B, then in normal case, is the virtual method of A overridden by C, or is the overridden method of B overridden by C?

Comment: @helloworld that's a purely theoretical question, but as my sample shows, it's the latter. `C` overrides the already overridden method of `B`. Actually, `C` does not even have knowledge of the existence of the same method from `A`. The override in `B` completely hides that from `C`. I hope this answers your question :)

Comment: So unless base keyword (like base.ClassAmethodname) is used in the overridden method in class B, the class C will not be indirectly overriding the Class A method, right?

Comment: I think I can answer that with `true` :-) Perhaps this helps: yes `B` could use the `base` keyword to call `A`'s version of the method, but `C` only ever communicates with `B`'s version of said method. Whether or not this is indirectly overriding, I say is up to you to say.

Comment: Thanks for that, I know this is a theoritical thing, and our thoughts seem to be aligned with respect to this concept. thanks

Answer (score 2):

according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149%28v=vs.110%29.aspx (take a look at picture)
when you override a virtual method and then derived that class in another class you inherit overriden implementation

```
    class A
    {
        public virtual void GetBonus(int value)
        {
            //if you define this method as seald no one can override this
        }
    }

    class B:A
    {
        public override void GetBonus(int value)
        {

        }
    }

    class C:B
    {
        public override void GetBonus(int value)
        {
            //here we override implementation of class B
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As per my knowledge, the method GetBonus in Class C:B overrides the method from Class A and not of Class B! Please can you correct me if wrong.

Comment: @helloworld if i don't misunderstand this the image in that link shows it inherits class B's implementation, take a look.